# different shape of the outputs when running to the forward() method of PyTorch NN

Tags: python, pytorch

Hello I'm trying to understand the following thing:

I have created the following neural network model using `PyTorch` to run a regression task.

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, h1, h2, out_features=0):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features,h1)    # input layer
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(h1, h2)            # hidden layer
        self.out = nn.Linear(h2, out_features)  # output layer
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.out(x)
        return x

model = Model(in_features=59, h1=64, h2=32, out_features=1)
```

Then we get to the training where I run the following code:

```
epochs = 300

losses = []

for i in range(epochs):
    
    y_pred = model(X_train)
    
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train)
    losses.append(loss.detach().numpy())
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Everything works fine but through the model's `forward()` method my `y_pred` gets the shape `[1359, 1]` (I guess it should be `[1359]` cause my `y_train` matches this shape and I get the following warning:

```
C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:528: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([1359])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1359, 1])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
```

This also happens when I try to evaluate my model

```
with torch.no_grad():
    
    y_val = model(X_test)
    
    loss = criterion(y_val.flatten(), y_test)
    
    print(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have a shape mismatch, your model will output a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 1)` while your target is shaped `(batch_size,)`. You have to explicitly broadcast your tensor such that the inputs of your criterion have shape.

Either by reshaping the prediction `y_val` itself:

```
>>> loss = criterion(y_val[:,0], y_test)
```

Or the target tensor `y_test`:

```
>>> loss = criterion(y_val, y_test[:,None])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I want to understand, is the code u provided what I should normally do or can it be incorporated directly in the preprocessing phase?

Comment: I mean is there any 'a priori' way in order for the model to output the correct shape?

Comment: A `nn.Linear` will always output a `n`-dimensional tensor where `n > 1` (in most cases `n = 2`). Your dataset can output the appropriate target shape though.